# How to find touch point angle in arc android

Tags: android, math, android-canvas

i supposed to create the below image using canvas android, here i want to find whether the user touch point is inside the arc (i.e wx1,wx2 .. wx7). i'm not sure about finding the angle for user touch. kindly provide me some suggestions.

Here is the code for drawing arc, sweep angle varies based on the condition

```
for (int i = 0; i < 360; i = (i + 20)) {

        if (i < 200 || i >= 340) {

            canvas.drawArc(rect, i, (float) 20.2, false, darkGrey);

        } else {

            canvas.drawArc(rect, i, (float) 19, false, lightGrey);

        }
    }
```

Here is the image

[image]

Comment: Implement onTouchListner and print motionEvent.getX() and motionEvent.getY()

Comment: yes i know the x and y touch point but how to find that point's belongs to which part of arc, i.e from wx1 to wx7

Comment: are you having different view for each arc

Comment: Look my edited answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to create your rectangles and somehow must be visible in the onTouch method. So , you will create the Rectangle dimensions of each drawable by hand that are related . to each ui element of your view. Attach a

> onTouchListener

to your view and the

> onTouch

method will be :

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      Log.d("Bounds","x : " + event.getX() + " y : "  + event.getY());

      if(rect1.contains((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY())){
        ....
      }else if(rect2.contains((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY())){

       ....
      }

      return false;
}
```

Take a look at the following references :

- [Rect reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html)
- [Rectf ref](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RectF.html)
- [a good example about rects](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.graphics.Rect)
- [Detect touch and draw rect on bitmap](http://android-er.blogspot.gr/2013/09/detect-touch-and-draw-rect-on-bitmap.html)

Comment: This is an arc with stroke width 80, how could it be possible to create rectangle for the arc, if i'm wrong please correct me.

Comment: Every slot in your graph could be a RectF rectangle. And you can use the same logic with code above. Just make visible the Rectangles in the onTouch method.

Comment: could be able to provide me some samples for reference